# open page when call function

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I select records from W3C Web SQL Database in my phonegap application. I create a button that call a function that delete the specific record in the db. 
When the record is deleted, the page "home" has to be automatically load and refresh with the new items. How can I do this?

```
function DeletedRecordSuccesful() 
{ 
alert("record Deleted.");

//open page "home"
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know this. I will to it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the followings to change page :

```
window.location =  "home.html"
```

or

```
window.location.href = "home.html"
```